# ServiceStack 'session' missing?

Tags: servicestack

new to this and trying to follow a tutorial on Pluralsight. A simple row of code:

```
var trackedData = (TrackedData)Session[date.ToString()];
```

has `Session` underlined with red and I have not succeeded in getting rid of it. When the tutor's mouse hovered over the session, following tip was displayed. `ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ISession Service.Session`

But somehow I couldn't get it into the solution. I have installed ServiceStack, ServiceStack.Host.MVC, ServiceStack.Host.AspNet and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a Service the dynamic untyped Session Bag was renamed to `base.SessionBag`.