# SessionBag missing in servicestack version 4.5.0

Tags: c#, api, inheritance, visual-studio-2013, servicestack

I am new to servicestack and using servicestack version 4.5.0.
With reference to the [ServiceStack 'session' missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363927/servicestack-session-missing)
**Where can I find this base.SessionBag property** ? with base keyword I am getting
[these intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckkzw.png)

please help me.

what does this line means:
**Inside a Service the dynamic untyped Session Bag was renamed to base.SessionBag.**

what does this line means:
**Inside a Service the dynamic untyped Session Bag was renamed to base.SessionBag.**
when I write base. I find following intellisense

```
base.Session //-- Property Method   
base.SaveSession //--- Extension  
base.SessionAs<>  
base.SessionFactory //-- Property Method   

public class EntryService : Service
{
    public object Post(Entry request)
    {
        var date = request.Time.Date;
        var trackedData = (TrackedData)Session= date.ToString();
        if(trackedData == null)
            trackedData = new TrackedData { Goal = 300 };

         trackedData.Total += request.Amount;
        Session[date.ToString()] = trackedData;

        return new EntryResponse { Id = 1};
    }

}
```

i want like this

```
  Session[date.ToString()] = trackedData;
```

but an error occurs  **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ISession**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inherit from ServiceStack's `Service` base class. You can then access the dynamic Session Bag with `base.SessionBag`.

Comment: I have already inherit it

Comment: I am getting this error while doing  Session[date.ToString()] = trackedData;     **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ServiceStack.CacheAccess.ISession**

Comment: @Kakashi_Hatake You can access the Session Bag with base.SessionBag.

Comment: I am unable to access Session Bag thorugh base.SessionBag. These are things I am getting http://i.stack.imgur.com/uhKHW.png

Comment: Then you're referencing an older version of ServiceStack, make sure all projects are using the latest version of ServiceStack. Check your /packages folder to make sure it's only referencing the latest v4.5.0 release.

Comment: Here is my package.config file information http://i.stack.imgur.com/eExZs.png

Comment: Here's the source code of the [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Service.cs#L91) containing the SessionBag property, check your /packages delete every version except for v4.5.0

Comment: Thank you so much you make my day